# Максимальное количество элементов в массиве

Tags: c++, массивы, mingw

Как определить максимально возможное количество элементов `n` в массиве, при таком объявлении:
    `int array[n];`
Где-то читал, что зависит от компилятора, у меня `MinGW 4.9.1 32bit`

Comment: Зависит от размера стека. В Windows вроде стандартно 1Мб, но можно увеличить (как - не помню) до 4, по-моему.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216259/is-there-a-max-array-length-limit-in-c Вот тут расписано на английском.

И тут: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488477/maximum-size-of-int-array